# Why is a regex search less efficient than a normal search?

Tags: algorithms, search

On a lot of messaging applications, regex search isn't enabled due to a "linear scan". I'm not sure why this is the case. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

"Linear scan" probably means the search can't backtrack. This guarantuees an O(n) complexity for the search. With backtracking it's possibly to get cases of exponential complexity. You might notice that that's not actually a problem for regular languages, since deciding regular languages doesn't need backtracking. Why then would regex search not be enabled due to wanting a "linear scan" of the chat history?

The issue is that many regular expression libraries actually don't just allow regular languages. For example, the standard regular expression library in Java uses backtracking to allow stuff like backreferences:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> Capturing groups are so named because, during a match, each
> subsequence of the input sequence that matches such a group is saved.
> The captured subsequence may be used later in the expression, via a
> back reference, and may also be retrieved from the matcher once the
> match operation is complete.

The docs don't explicitely say this, but this is only possible because the matcher can backtrack.

So, I would take the informed assumption that regex search is disabled because a linear search is wanted, but the regex library used actually does more.

Note: There are regex libraries that do a linear scan. They don't allow backreference and lookaround but most other features still work. See

- https://github.com/google/re2j

> Java's standard regular expression package, java.util.regex, and many
> other widely used regular expression packages such as PCRE, Perl and
> Python use a backtracking implementation strategy: when a pattern
> presents two alternatives such as a|b, the engine will try to match
> subpattern a first, and if that yields no match, it will reset the
> input stream and try to match b instead.
>
> If such choices are deeply nested, this strategy requires an
> exponential number of passes over the input data before it can detect
> whether the input matches. If the input is large, it is easy to
> construct a pattern whose running time would exceed the lifetime of
> the universe. This creates a security risk when accepting regular
> expression patterns from untrusted sources, such as users of a web
> application.
>
> In contrast, the RE2 algorithm explores all matches simultaneously in
> a single pass over the input data by using a nondeterministic finite
> automaton.
>
> There are certain features of PCRE or Perl regular expressions that
> cannot be implemented in linear time, for example, backreferences, but
> the vast majority of regular expressions patterns in practice avoid
> such features.

- https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2

> RE2 was designed and implemented with an explicit goal of being able
> to handle regular expressions from untrusted users without risk. One
> of its primary guarantees is that the match time is linear in the
> length of the input string.[...]
>
> It is also not a goal to implement all of the features offered by
> Perl, PCRE and other engines. As a matter of principle, RE2 does not
> support constructs for which only backtracking solutions are known to
> exist. Thus, backreferences and look-around assertions are not
> supported.

Comment: I'm noticing that there two types of linear (linear in the length of the input of the string and linear in the number of messages to scan through)